# How to implement Camera function in windows forms?

Tags: vb.net, camera, device

I'm working in a proyect in VB.NET who will run in .net frameworks 4.5 (windows 8.1).

I need to implement a function to add the posibility to take pictures INSIDE my application.

Can anyone help me saying what's the right way to implement?

(What class,functions,interfacts to use..etc

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control

Comment: Spoiler...it [looks like this](http://images.wired.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/1413474840_Matrix-Wallpapers.jpg) inside